# Evenly distributing overlapping shapes along a line

Tags: geometry

I want to photograph a road 1km in length from above. Every photograph I take should cover 400m of the road. Therefore, I will need 3 photos to completely cover the road.

I want the photographs to overlap somewhat so they can be stitched together. I would also like them to "overhang" the ends of the road section to be photographed, due to margin of error in where the photo is actually taken (drone photography - may not take photo precisely where specified).

The photographs should overlap evenly (photo 1&2 overlapping area is the same as photo 2&3) and the overhang of the end photos should also be the same size as the overlap. See terrible paint drawing below.

[image: illustration of overlap]

How can I work out the centre points of these photographs?

How can I generalise this problem for any survey distance and any photograph size?

Answer (score 0):

First you can compute $x$ by setting up an equation. You have $3$ times $400m$ picture range and this should cover $1000m$ of road plus $6$ times $x$ (twice on the edges and twice each in the center). This gives $x=33.3m$.

The center point of the first picture is $x$ meters before the $200m$ mark on the road, so at $166.7m$, the second one is exactly in the middle, or $400m - 2x = 333.3m$ from the first. The last one is $166.7$ from the end or $833.3m$ from the start.